# Paypal : how to implement very simple payment form

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make a part of my site to pay some depts that people have about me, so I want to make a simple way to doing that: paypal!

In fact, I want to make a form where the user put the value, and when he submit it, the bill will be create from the user to my paypal account... and then he will pay it :-)

I already make the use of the api but I don't need to make a return and cancel code, ipn and so on!

I don't know how write the code for doing this...

thanks to read me :-)

Comment: Did you chedked my comment about your answer?

Comment: Pls check this [link](https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=SB7N1TNTMNsVXD7D_k-hBryW08ANFOohLKSeIpNRA1voDT4WTTXDfPMLJMm&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8d333dc9aadeed3fe0b5b299d55fd35542)